# Why and how `a+++b` is interpreted as `(a++) + b` and not `a + (++b)`?

Tags: c#, algorithm, language-agnostic, tokenize

How does the compiler's lexer/tokenizer "makes sense" out of : `a+++b` ? as in:

```
int a=0,b=0,x=0;
x = a+++b;
```

I assume it uses some [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree#Description), maybe a [generalized suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree), but if so, then why the longer token (`++`) is interpreted before the shorter (`+`), and not vice versa ? meaning why it is interpreted as:

```
(a++) + b
```

and not:

```
a + (++b)
```

?

I need to write some kind of tokenizer on my own, and was wondering about it.

Comment: It could also have been seen as `a + +(+b)` with two unary plusses before `b` and no increments!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch

Comment: @BenVoigt - this is exactly the point. So this problem cannot be solved by simple tokenizer algorithm, you'd have to go one level higher and let the lexer know about context ?

Comment: `a++ + b` : This is known as the [`maximal munch rule`, or `longest match rule`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Scanner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language designers know about ambiguities like this, and outlaw "the wrong case" in the reference manual.

For the lexer, this is pretty easy: choose the longest legal lexeme. When faced with "++" and "+", choose "++".  Most lexer generators implement this policy directly, and it isn't hard to do this in a hand-coded lexer, because you have to check for the possibility of a second "+" anyway after you've seen the first.

Comment: regarding "lexer generators", this is very problematic, as [@Ben Voigt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121048/why-and-how-ab-is-interpreted-as-a-b-and-not-a-b#comment28275009_19121048) commented above: can the [maximal munch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) be overcome algorithmically ?

Comment: The way Ben put it, maximal munch isn't the problem, its the *solution* in this case: take the longest token.  If the question was, "why does language FOOBAR parse A+++B as A+ ++B", the answer on the reference manual side would be the same: it is *defined* that way.  But a standard lexer, doing maximal munch, would be a problem here.  A hand written lexer can be bent easily to do either, as needed by the language definitions.   If you want a fun problem, consider how ">>" should be lexed in C++:  a shift operator, or two template closing braces?  Here maximal munch simply isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The lexer usually is greedy, that means that if a token can match a string larger than other string also matching another (or the same) token, it will match the bigger string.

in this example the lexer will first match the "a" character and think that "identifiers" (or "variable") is a potential token (also any other token that can start with the a letter, like "abstract" or "as"), after that the lexer will read the following char ("+") and as a+ can't  be and identifier, nor is "abstract" neither "as", he will stop searching a candidate for "a" and tokenize it as an identifier.

after that he has the "+" as the current symbol, and think about potential tokens matching that ("+", "++", "+="), because of the "greedyness" the lexer tries to continue with the next char and gets the following "+" so he concludes that the only token that can match is "++" (if "+++" were a valid token the lexer needs to discard if the following symbol is a +)

The folowing step takes the following char (again "+") and think about the possible tokens ("+", "++", "+="), he will take the following char ("b") and as "+b" is not a potential prefix of any token, he determines that the following token is "+" .

Then he continue with "b" (potentially identifier or any b starting keyword ("base", "bool", "break", "byte") but reading the following char (";") the lexer determines that is an identifier.

so the lexers produce the following tokens

identifier ++ + identifier ;